# Delete special cells base on criteria such as blanks or highlights

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have some reports that need to be modified by deleting some specific cells such as blank cells or highlights in the background

I have tried to record Macro to delete the special cells. however, the position will be changed regarding the difference of the row numbers. I could not specify the certain position of each cell.

Here is my data

[image]

here is what I expect to get

[image]

Here is my recorded Macro

```
Sub Macro1()

 'Macro1 Macro

    Range("B4").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("B16").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("B24").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=12
    Range("B30").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below, change the columns you want to delete

you can change criteria by using xlcelltype XXXX

for xample of xlcelltype

[image]

```
Dim b As Range

For Each b In [B1:B2000].SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks, 1).Offset(0, -1).Areas
    b.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Next
    
    
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.Autofit

        
End Sub
```

Comment: you can also set the ranges of finding to avoid long process